# Is there a way to extend String in new class in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to be able create (or extend from String) a TypeScript type that behaves like String.
To be able to assign value like: `const object: MyCustomString = 'some value'`

Comment: Why do you need this? Can't you just store the string in a field of your object?

Comment: It's not possible to directly do what you want to do. You can modify the String prototype but perhaps a better question is what are you actually trying to do because this sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I think you are looking for branded types: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49260143/how-do-you-emulate-nominal-typing-in-typescript/49260286#49260286

Comment: I ma trying to represent a XML tag of xliff document
`<translation-unit>
    <source translate="false">Some text for translation</source>
    <target approved="false">Some translated text</source>
</translation-unit>`
So the tag `<source>` is mainly string but has some attributes and i want to access it like `TranslationUnit.Source = 'Some text to translate'; TranslationUnit.Source.translate=true;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I quote the [documentation on *extends*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends):

> The `extends` keyword can be used to subclass custom classes as well as built-in objects.

So, it is authorized to subclass built-in types in ES2015:

```
class MyString extends String {
    get specialProp() {
        return this + " is special!" 
    }
}

const s = new MyString("abc");
console.log(s.specialProp); // abc is special!
```

Or, other example:

```
class SourceString extends String {
    constructor(s: string, public translate = false) {
        super(s);
    }
}

const s = new SourceString("abc", true);
console.log(s.translate); // true
```

Notice: Instances of your custom class [won't be `string` primitives but `String` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects):

```
console.log(typeof s); // "object"
console.log(s instanceof String); // true
```

Comment: This is near to what i thought.
I found definition of `String` on GitHub [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/2c9f7e6ef1aabc83a25db34adeeaea6da2ddaff6/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L394) and [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/2c9f7e6ef1aabc83a25db34adeeaea6da2ddaff6/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L517)
\n I would like something like this if its possible,
when i try to implement the `StringConstructor {...` i get issues with implementing `(value?: any): boolean;`, gives me an error Type `'SourceString' provides no match for the signature '(value?: any): string'.`

Comment: @JackDaniels I don't understand the error. Could you give your code?

Comment: `interface SourceConstructor {
    new(value?: any): String;
    (value?: any): string;
    readonly prototype: String;
    fromCharCode(...codes: number[]): string;
}

class SourceString implements SourceConstructor {
  
  prototype: string;

  fromCodePoint(...codes: any[]) {
    return 'sdfsdf';
  }
  fromCharCode(...codes: number[]){
    return 'test';
  };
}`

Comment: @JackDaniels I'm sorry I can't help with that. The code you post contains a lot of errors. And I can't understand why it would be needed. Just use the code I suggest. Or write another question.