# Force generic type to be the type of a unique symbol in typescript

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49260286/2954288) about nominal typing I thought to move it one step further with

```typescript
export type MARKED<C, M> = C & {
  readonly m: M;
};
```

and to be used like

```typescript
const readonly SPECIAL: unique symbol = Symbol();
isSpecial(value: C): value is MARKED<C, typeof SPECIAL> {
  return someVerificationOf(value);
}
```

Here I try to be extra safe by replacing the "brand" with a unique symbol, though `MARKED` could as well be used with just a string as

```typescript
class Foo { ... };
type SpecialFoo = MARKED<Foo, 'special'>;
```

Is there a chance to force the 2nd generic parameter of `MARKED` to be a `unique symbol`? I tried things like

```typescript
type MARKED<C, M extends unique symbol> = ...
```

but this is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Please see the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#unique-symbol)

> To enable treating symbols as unique literals a new type unique symbol is available. unique symbol is a subtype of symbol, and are produced only from calling Symbol() or Symbol.for(), or from explicit type annotations. The new type is only allowed on const declarations and readonly static properties, `and in order to reference a specific unique symbol, you’ll have to use the typeof operator`. Each reference to a unique symbol implies a completely unique identity that’s tied to a given declaration.

Especially this: `in order to reference a specific unique symbol, you’ll have to use the typeof operator`

Hence, in order to use `unique symbol` constraint, you need to use `typeof`:

```js
const UNIQUE: unique symbol = Symbol();

type MARKED<U extends typeof UNIQUE> = U

type Result = MARKED<typeof UNIQUE>
```

But, I'd willing to bet, that you have several `unique symbols` and you don't want to create utility type for each symbol.

Let's take a look closer to this line: `unique symbol is a subtype of symbol`.

What it gives us?

`unique symbol` is a subtype of symbol. It gives us a door for checking whether some type is a subtype of symbol or not. It is already something.

So, we need to check whether passed type is a subtype of `symbol`:

```js
type IsUnique<UniqueSymbol extends symbol> =
    (UniqueSymbol extends symbol
        ? (symbol extends UniqueSymbol
            ? false
            : true
        )
        : false
    )

// true
type Check = IsUnique<symbol & { tag: 42 }>
```

Above util does not meet our requirements.

We need also to check if symbol contains only `symbol` keys.

```js
type IsExactKeys<S extends symbol> =
    (keyof S extends SYMBOL_KEYS
        ? (SYMBOL_KEYS extends keyof S
            ? true
            : false
        )
        : false
    )

type IsUnique<UniqueSymbol extends symbol> =
    (UniqueSymbol extends symbol
        ? (symbol extends UniqueSymbol
            ? false
            : IsExactKeys<UniqueSymbol>
        )
        : false
    )
// never
type Check = IsUnique<never>
```

Ooops, it still does not work with `never`.

Let's handle `never` type:

```js
const UNIQUE: unique symbol = Symbol();
const REGULAR: symbol = Symbol()

type SYMBOL_KEYS = keyof symbol;

type IsExactKeys<S extends symbol> =
    (keyof S extends SYMBOL_KEYS
        ? (SYMBOL_KEYS extends keyof S
            ? true
            : false
        )
        : false
    )

// credits goes to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40248
type IsNever<T> = [T] extends [never] ? true : false;

type IsUnique<UniqueSymbol extends symbol> =
    (IsNever<UniqueSymbol> extends true ? false
        : (UniqueSymbol extends symbol
            ? (symbol extends UniqueSymbol
                ? false
                : IsExactKeys<UniqueSymbol>
            )
            : false
        )
    );

type Assert<T extends true> = T

type Unique = {
    readonly StaticSymbol: unique symbol
}['StaticSymbol']

/**
 * Ok
 */
type Test0_0 = Assert<IsUnique<Unique>> // ok
type Test0 = Assert<IsUnique<typeof UNIQUE>> // ok

/**
 * Expected errors
 */
type Test1 = Assert<IsUnique<typeof REGULAR>> // error
type Test2 = Assert<IsUnique<
    & typeof REGULAR
    & { readonly tag: unique symbol }
>> // error

type Test3 = Assert<IsUnique<symbol>> // error
type Test4 = Assert<IsUnique<any>> // error
type Test5 = Assert<IsUnique<unknown>> // error
type Test6 = Assert<IsUnique<never>> // error


export type MARKED<C, M extends symbol> =
    IsUnique<M> extends true ? C & {
        readonly m: M;
    } : never
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-JZuAWZx5jP+Q5XMiwAAM1krakNxtNQQdcvD2VyGYzcDARZBNorMFrbHrF0bYPlsRBg2Q6CwbbgHa7ReA2dzcHzoQMkTIqReEwmYAmUGLpYo5dgAEY60aR7Em+PJ14JNJ5GI5wuLvuJie+7AAExXhtbzHcNYhmAAyOAH3EKRZAUcC4CdOA3Q9L0fT9ABzUN5RRVRo2AN9Ow-A87TLfsAGYAJvO8QMjAjd0-b8zxgAAWSiTSA5swggKg6KIr9eyYgBWNjR2bAhnAgMAAHcIF4vdiIE-sADYRI48dPnOCY5IY4BEj0A94F7EwFHsAARWIAGEABo4BMc0qlovImmoyFYhMXIuQtP5SQsuAIJdQVkM9CBvTgGhcBMIQmmjOBcA0i4gA)

Seems to be it works now. Please keep in mind, above constraint is indirect. I'd say that it is a `duck` constraint.

If something is:

- a subtype of symbol
- has same keys as a symbol
- is not never
- symbol is not assignable to passed type but passed type is assignable to symbol

then, probably we have a deal with `unique symbol`.

Please add more tests.

Please trust above code only for 90%.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to the question formulated in the subject but to the targeted problem of getting **nominal typing** in typescript without the danger of  intricate name collisions that may happen with "brand" type nominal typing as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49260286/2954288).

Suppose we have

```js
class Foo { ... }
```

yet under certain circumstances, in particular after verifying some constraint of a `Foo` object, we want to carry along the information that the constraint holds. We use the following:

```js
const VERIFIED_FOO = Symbol();
type VerifiedFoo = Foo & {
  readonly [VERIFIED_FOO]: undefined;
}
isFoo(foo: Foo) foo is VerifiedFoo {
  return elaborateFooVerificationPassed(foo);
}
```

By using a `Symbol` as the property name in the attached marker type, we should be safe from spurious name clashes. Further, a `VerifiedFoo` can be used everywhere a `Foo` can be used, but not the other way round. Finally, after using the type guard `isFoo`, the compiler knows it and helps to not confuse the two types. This can be used, for example, like:

```
handle(foo: Foo): void {
  if (isFoo(foo)) {
    // Here we know it is a VerifiedFoo, not just Foo
    // and in particular the compiler knows it too.
    doHandle(foo);
  }
}
private doHandle(foo: VerifiedFoo): void {
  // no need to handle special cases for non verified foo objects
}
```