# Specialising arithmetic types to prevent illegal operations

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, I would like the convenience of normal arithmetic operations:

```
const totalWeight = baseWeight + loadWeight
```

But I would like to prevent accidentally mixing units.

I tried something naive:

```
type Ounce = number;
type Gram = number;
const x: Ounce = 1;
const y: Gram = 2;
x + y;
```

... hoping it would give me a type error, but it didn't.

Is there a way to achieve this? Bonus credits if it could validate `const s: Velocity = distance / time`

Comment: See also e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/49260143/3001761.

Comment: Your "bonus credits" line at the end would need a decent amount of work to achieve.  The best you could get is `divide(distance, time)` (there's nothing we can do to numeric operators like `/` here) and have some kind of mass/length/time exponent counter inside our dimension types.  Seems fun but out of scope for a "bonus".

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7OboN) for the bonus?